# Show TableViewCell results after updating data

Tags: uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm doing personal projects to learn more about Swift. Right now, I'm working Bill Alert App just to test concepts and learn Swift concepts.

I'm using a TabBar where Item 1 is a outstanding bills which is addable while Bills Paid (BillLogTableViewController) consists of bills that I've marked as Paid.

All these records are entered into SQLLite via Core Data.

After marking an outstanding bill as paid, and I tap on BillLogTableViewController I noticed that the latest bill that I just tapped as 'Paid' isn't display.

I found a way to resolve this by calling the bill table where paid = 'Y' 
in BillLogTableViewController didLoad.

However, I would like to know if there is a better way to do it without calling the table whenever I tap on the Bill Paid tab such as displaying the data in the Bill Log tab whenever a bill is marked as 'Paid' automatically.

Totally appreciated for any suggestions given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `tableView.reloadData()` when you change your model.

It is perfectly fine to call it on `viewWillAppear()` in the View Controller containg the UITableView.

Comment: Where do I place it this? In BillLogTableViewControlle or OutstandingBillTableViewController? If I put it in OutstandingBillTableViewController, where will the trigger point be?

Comment: If the first one just makes changes to another, it is fine to put in in viewWillAppear of the second VC.

Comment: The second option would be to get a reference to other tableView and call it from there, or post a NSNotification each time you change the model, and listen in the second view controller to update it. But the easiest way is to set it in viewWillAppear in your case.

Comment: Roger that,  performance wise, will it have an impact? Since every time, I click on BillLogTableViewController, it will call the paid = 'Y' using CoreData? I was thinking perhaps there's a better way where a bill marked as Paid will automatically be reflected in the LogViewController.

Comment: The perfomance shouldn't be an issue even if you have 10 000 records.

Comment: You could also keep a "global" array (not really global, but be able to reference it from both VCs) of payed bills, and just add it or remove it from there. You would then use this array as model for the table view. This way you only fetch once, and when you reload table view, it is super fast.